# Add date-picker to slack dialog?

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-dialog

I want to add date-picker elements to slack dialog. It is clear that from 
[documentation](https://api.slack.com/dialogs#elements), we can only add input, text-area, and select elements.

Is there any hack to use date-picker in the slack dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a latest update to the slack api,[Block Kit in modals](https://api.slack.com/block-kit/surfaces/modals#handling_submissions).

This is like dialog but with all block elements access and they also have many cool features for dynamic views.

Here 
[This is snippet of data-picker block integrated into it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMr7e.png)

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you will find a viable hack since your Slack app needs to run on all platforms supported by Slack clients incl. Windows, MAC, Android and iOS.

Instead, I would suggest to design your interaction with [blocks](https://api.slack.com/reference/messaging/blocks). There you have a [datepicker](https://api.slack.com/reference/messaging/block-elements#datepicker) element

Comment: I need to create form kind of UI where I can select from and to dates and submit. If I use blocks for the date-pickers, slack will send post request for each select which is difficult to manage state.

Comment: yes, its a bit more complicated to manage than a modal window, but it works. And its the only datapicker that Slack offers. Your only other alternative I think is to implement your dialog outside Slack in a browser.

Comment: I didn't really get you what do you mean by `implementing your dialog outside slack in browser`. Can you elaborate on it?

Comment: You could take the user outside Slack to a website, handle the input on the web site and then go back to the Slack app. e.g. use could click on a link button to open a page on your web site.

Comment: Yes. completely good idea. I feel like taking the user from slack to browser is not a good thing if we consider the UX

Comment: Agreed. Its more like a last resort if you have some really complex user input that can not be implemented within Slack. But if you only need a datepicker I would stay within Slack. Much easier to implement it with layout blocks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196065/discussion-between-subbu-and-erik-kalkoken).